# Avoiding an "unchecked call" warning when using a JList

Tags: java, swing, warnings, actionlistener, jlist

I am making a simple file-searching program that presents a GUI. It functions perfectly, however, I get a warning on compile time in my search-button `ActionListener` when I update the output `JList`. Is there anyway to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Java 7, the class [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) has supported generics. The compiler complains when they are missing. You can use

```
JList<String> resultList = new JList<>();
```

Comment: Excellent, the warning is gone! Thanks